# C++ how to compact fancy for-loops

Tags: c++, loops, macros

If one is too lazy to rewrite a fancy loop on some variable u, one can define a macro like this:

```
#define forloop(u) for (int u = 0; u < N; u++)
```

Now, let's say I want to do this

```
for (int u = 0; u < N; u++) {
    Class& var_u = someFunctionOf(u)
    ... code using var_u ...
}
```

And let's say I need to do that at several places in the code, and I am too lazy to rewrite it, because the loop involves complicated conditions on multiple variables. How can I compress it into a macro ? I feel it is annoying to put only one { in the macro because whatever IDE you are using it will break syntax highlighting and everything...

I actually just had an idea:
Define a template:

```
template <typename Loop> void forloop(int u, const Loop& loop) {
    for (int u = 0; u < N; u++) {
        Class& var_u = someFunctionOf(u)
        loop(u, var_u);
    }
}
```

So that I only have to write:

```
forloop([&](int u, Class& var_u){
    ... code using var_u ...
});
```

I know, I'm weird. Is that a good idea? Will everything be inlined 100% of the time? Do I not lose any performance by doing that instead of regular for loop? Performance is critical in my case.

Other way I thought about:

```
#define forloop(u, var_u) for (int u = 0; u < N; u++) { Class& var_u = someFunctionOf(u)
#define forloop_end }
```

Now call:

```
forloop(u, var_u)
... code using var_u ...
forloop_end
```

Now it is not so good because {} disappeared, so an IDE syntax checker can get confused if I use same variable names inside the loop as variables defined earlier outside of the loop. So I thought maybe one can do this:

```
forloop(u, var_u) {
... code using var_u ...
} forloop_end
```

But then does the extra layer of { } reduces performance (even very slightly)?
Feels like the two } will mean 2 rounds of object destruction. Is that slower than destroying the same set of objects in one round only? Intuitively it feels like some stack pointer would have to move twice instead of once, but maybe compiler is smart enough to optimize that?

Yes I care about speed and don't want my loops to be slower than the regular way, but I feel it would help code readability to remove those annoying reference initializations at the beginning of every loop in my code.

Thank you for comments and suggestions.

Comment: Why not simply use a range based loop?

Comment: I feel its complicated sometime i need to iterate and stop early so I dont know if  its very doable with range based loop

Comment: Methinks [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) is your friend.

Comment: And get a better IDE that can handle macros :)

Comment: Which IDE does that

Comment: I am writing graph stuff with custom data structure. It feels like a tedious approach to define iterators and stuff like that just to be compliant to some standard. And I want efficiency. So do you have better arguments?

Comment: Please avoid hiding control flow inside macros, it quickly makes for completely unreadable code for the uninitiated to your specific conventions. [You may be rightly sentenced to maintaining the original Bourne shell.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050106-00/?p=36783)

Comment: Sorry I was serious. I did not mean to be aggressive. Why is it good to define iterators like that. I just wanted to hear some explanation of why you think it is better than the template approach if you think it is. Thanks

Comment: BTW there is nothing wrong with having one macro with opening brace and another with closing. LLVM's libc++ standard library does that. For example,  see `_LIBCPP_DECLARE_STRONG_ENUM` defined [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/9b69be4b1f89aba162a4dc6a245061b37032f05f/include/__config#L841-L847) and being used [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/9b69be4b1f89aba162a4dc6a245061b37032f05f/include/future#L384-L391)

Comment: OK your point is readabililty. But I feel like IF I have to rewrite all my reference definition at every loop to access, head, tail node, arc, reverse arc, etc it become quite unreadable too. So here is the issue.

Comment: @J.M Qt Creator with the clang code model handles this just fine, but it's not a good reason to do it. Also, the double curly braces performance argument is the height of misguided premature optimization - no decent compiler in the last 20+ years moves the stack pointer for braces, stack frame allocation is generally done just once at the beginning of the function.

Comment: OK I guess I will probably use that solution then.

Comment: I am with @MatteoItalia . Just tried 2 macros with opening and closing braces and it swallows them just fine. I am not even using the clang code model

Comment: Yes yes I will use that it is my best compromise for readability

Comment: Wait, I never said that it's a good idea. The better one IMO is the template one. No obscure macros, no hidden control flow, no risk of name clashes, the caller gets to decide how stuff is named and you are almost sure that everything gets inlined anyway. Defining iterators OTOH may be a PITA, but, besides giving you the range based for loop for free, allows you to play nice with the algorithms library. It's up to you to decide whether it's worth the pain.

Comment: @MatteoItalia "Wait, I never said that it's a good idea"... ROFL

Answer (score 2):

Write `index_range`.  Write `map_range`.

```
for (auto& var_u: map_range(someFunctionOf)( index_range(0,N) ) ){
  ... code using var_u ...
}
```

compress by storing `map_range(someFunctionOf)` somewhere shared, or even the index range.

You never have guarantees that things are inlined.  Write clean compile-time abstract code and profile if it matters.

Comment: So is that any better than the template approach. If so why?